# How to know where is the location path of React Native?

Tags: react-native

How to know the location path of my React Native? Because I want to move it in my D disk.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the react-native npm package global u can get the install path using the command: `npm list -g` if u installed it locally on project level it should be in the node_modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

If it's local installation as in my case just type : npm list.
The first line on figure shows path[image]